# Revert few files of a commit

Tags: github, github-desktop

I have created a branch from master and I have made changes to files say `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4` and added a new file `new_file5`. And pushed the changes to the branch. Again made changes to `file2`, `file3`, `file4` and again pushed my codes to the branch. I made a total of 3 commits to that branch. Now I have raised a pull request to merge it into master. The reviewer says that I should never have made any changes to `file1` and the file `new_file5` is not required, few lines of the code of `file3` is to be reverted to its original state and rest of the code changes are required.

1. How do I revert all the changes of `file1` to its original state?
2. How do I revert few lines of the code to its original state in
   `file3`?

Comment: Are you using an IDE with a Git enabled plugin?  Your first requirement can easily be done from the command line.  The second one is more difficult, and a side-by-side diff is probably the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am fairly new to github and have used Github-Desktop mostly. Can you tell me how to do the first one. And how do I revert the second one with side by side comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first requirement, you may checkout `file1` at the earlier commit:

```
git checkout ABCD1234 path/to/file1
```

Here `ABCD1234` is the SHA-1 *hash* of the earlier commit, in which `file1` had the version you want.

For the second requirement with `file3`, you can't simply revert to the earlier version, because you only want to change some of the contents.  The best way to handle this would be to use a Git plugin diff tool, which can show `file3` in the earlier version side-by-side the current version.  In absence of this, you may open `file3` in GitHub at the earlier commit and then just cut and paste what you need.

By the way, to find the SHA-1 hashes of the earlier commits for both requirements, just type `git log` from the bash, and then find the earlier commits of interest, using the commit messages to help you.